# Transform CSS at build time. Can I do this with SASS or LESS?

Tags: css, sass, less

I am completely new with either SASS and LESS (I know the concept, but never used them), but I know CSS. This question is about is the idea or direction is good, or should I look for other?

I am facing the the following task: I need to have create .CSS files as usual *except* all selectors must be selective within a single div (with its id). So the normal reset should be like:

```
/* ...*/
div#mydivid h1, div#mydivid h2, div#mydivid h3, div#mydivid h4, div#mydivid div#mydivid h5 {
    /* ...*/
}

instead of:
/* ...*/
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    /* ...*/
}
/* ...*/
```

Obviously I could manually maintain this, and rewrite my (and other's) standard CCS-s, but I am hoping that I can still write my CSS (and use existing ones) in the standard way, and a build time a preprocessor generates the transformed ones, what I will actually link to my pages.

Is this possible? Has anybody better idea? 
(I do not think it should matter but this is VS 2013, and C# / ASP.NET)

Comment: Sounds like a strange requirement. CSS scopes are not really usefel yet, ut this looks like a use case fro those: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ascope & http://davidwalsh.name/scoped-css

Comment: What are you trying to do? What you are asking here leads to bloated CSS.

Comment: Yes I know. This is not a usual web site. This is a special task within one or more usual web site, and must be not interfer with anything existing

Comment: You can also use an `iframe` to encapsulate a specific part of a website (e.g. an advertisement banner)

Comment: Do not ask about multiple unrelated languages in the same question:  choose one or the other.  Also, you need to be doing your research about the languages in question *before* asking your question.

Comment: @feeela: iframe was my first idea, however it must work with any website regardless what xframe options are in effect.

Comment: @cimmanon: 1) I think sass/less are indeed_related_, oppositely as you state. 2) Many valuable (50+ votes)  questions and answers are here what are mention more than one language even in their title 3) I truly believe developing is not equals with coding. If we agree in this, then it is also obvious, that there are questions what not are not about languages and not necessary specific to a particular language.

Comment: No, they are *not* related any more than JavaScript and PHP are related.  They happen to have a similar syntax for some of their control structures, but are otherwise very different.  Again, if you did any actual research on either language before asking your question, you would have had your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Less or SASS/SCSS you may wrap the entire stylesheet into a `div`. But [SASS has a feature to break out of any wrappers called `@at-root`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root).

You may even wrap the includes to get a wrapper around any stylesheets (SCSS):

```
div#mydivid {
    @include _layout.scss
    @include _module1.scss
}

/* or */
div#mydivid {
    #{headings(1,6)} {
        color: #333;
    }
}
```

The latter results in:

```
div#mydivid h1,
div#mydivid h2,
div#mydivid h3,
div#mydivid h4,
div#mydivid h5,
div#mydivid h6 {
    color: #333;
}
```